# flutter Push Notifications

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

ive currently been trying to set up push notifications for my flutter app using fcm, and I came across an article that said that i need a paid Apple developer account, is this really the only way or is there another way to do it.

Comment: For iOS , Yes this is only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need paid Apple Developer program membership in order to use push notifications within your application.